# Simulate graph model in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, social-networking

I have a very specific graph problem in networkx:

My directed graph has two different type of nodes ( i will call them **I** and **T**) and it is built with edges only between **I-T** and **T-I** (so T doesn't connect with other T and the same with I)

Now I need to simulate a new graph with the same behavior: i have a certain number of I and T and the edge between I-T exists with a certain probability (also for T-I but with different probability, let's call them **p_i** and **p_o**).

So my problem is that i can't iterate with for loops both for I and then for T because both are quite big (the data I'm analyzing right now are 5000 T's and 5000 I's but the will probably increase up to 300000 each) and my pc can't handle that.

What is the best way to create a graph in this situation?

Comment: Could you clarify on the an edge exists with probability?

Comment: By looking at the data of the first graph (that is a real graph) I obtain the proportion of my edges on the possible number of them. I  use this proportion as a probability for the simulated graph. I don't know if it's clearer like this

Comment: How big is "quite big"? Please give a number. Also, your graph is called a **bipartite** graph. I suggest trying https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.generators.bipartite.bipartite_random_graph.html

Comment: "So my problem is that i can't iterate with for loops ... because both are quite big and my pc can't handle that."  This is very strange and seems to be your real problem.  What exactly happens when you try?  ( I regularly use code that iterates over graphs with a million plus nodes )

Comment: The data I'm using now are like 5000 T and 5000 I but i have multiple file I need to analyze, the last one probably has 300000 T and the same number of I's. So I tried with my actual data both using the @Stef answer and by doing two for loops and it worked. I just maybe need to find a better solution for the future, also because by using a standardized method for all my data it will be way faster to analyze monthly dataset of almost 10 years.

Comment: @DuccioBorchi Please edit your question with the relevant information (5000 for T and 5000 for I) rather than specifying it here in the comments. Also please consider posting an answer to your own question (in an answer, not by editing the question). In particular, how did you use `bipartite_random_graph`? From the documentation, it only accepts one probability parameter; i.e., the probability for edges I->T will be the same as for edges T->I. It might be possible to work around this, but it's sufficiently non-obvious that I would be interested in seeing how you did it.

Comment: " by doing two for loops and it worked."  But it didn't work before?  Something does not make sense!

Comment: I tried before with the whole dataset and it didn't work, after that i split the data monthly (because i needed it for my analysis) and it worked for the first month (the one with 5000 T and I) that is also the less numerous. I'm sorry if I'm not clear but it is my 3rd or 4th question posted on this and the other ones were simplier.

Comment: "and it didn't work,"  What exactly happened when it ( whatever it is ) didn't work ( second or third time of asking.  )

Comment: @Stef I just used one probability for both I->T and T->I because in the data i'm using now they are almost the same number. If one dataset is not as balanced as the one I'm using i prefer using the double for. But even the bipartite answer is useful as in the analysis i will need to considerate the graph as undirected

Comment: @ravenspoint the pc freeze or the program will not respond

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger to find out what causes those symptoms of a coding error.

Comment: Networkx is slow compared to other graph libraries, and your problem seems to be performance-wise - have you considered e.g. networkit? See e.g. this benchmark https://www.timlrx.com/blog/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that [@ravenspoint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16582/ravenspoint) makes me reach with his comment.

For `T=5000` and `I=5000` it works by doing `for loops` in `I` and one in `T` and by using `np.random.binomial(1, pi, nI)` and  `np.random.binomial(1, po, nO)` from `numpy`, where `nO` and `nI` are the length of `O` and `I` in the real graph and creating edges if **these arrays are 1**.

If `po=pi` (as it happens in my example) also [@Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080723/stef) solution works and you can use `nx.bipartite.random_graph(countadd, countt, p, seed=None,directed=True)`